# Combinatorics formula seemingly overcounting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Recently I've been searching the formula to compute the probability of obtaining certain cards combinations. My researches came across a formula, and I tried to extend it to a more general use. However, my extended version does not seem to be correct, as it likely overcounts. My first formula basically calculates the probability of obtaining l times different k of a kind amongst n drawn cards. Formula is the following :
$$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}13\\l\end{pmatrix}\cdot{\begin{pmatrix}4\\k\end{pmatrix}}^l\cdot\begin{pmatrix}13-l\\n-kl\end{pmatrix}\cdot4^{n-kl}}{\begin{pmatrix}52\\n\end{pmatrix}}$$
Seemingly this is correct, probabilities appear realistic to me and I've never came across probabilities superior to one. To help you understanding this formula, here is an example : we would like to obtain 3 different two of a kind amongst 8 drawn cards, which means $l=3$, $k=2$, and $n=8$. We get : $$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}13\\3\end{pmatrix}\cdot{\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}}^3\cdot\begin{pmatrix}10\\2\end{pmatrix}\cdot4^2}{\begin{pmatrix}52\\8\end{pmatrix}}$$
So here's how it works : $\begin{pmatrix}13\\3\end{pmatrix}$ is the number of possible triple two of a kind ranks combinations. ${\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}}^3$ is the number of ways the the three two of a kind can be drawn (depending on if the cards are clubs, spades, diamonds, or hearts). $\begin{pmatrix}10\\2\end{pmatrix}\cdot4^2$ is the possible combinations for the 2 remaining cards, and finally $\begin{pmatrix}52\\8\end{pmatrix}$ is the number of possible combination of 8 cards (which you maybe guessed). For this very example, the probability is about $0.0591$.

The reason why I wanted to extend this formula is basically the formula I explained above only computes the probabiliy of getting exactlly l k of a kind, but no other special combination. So I tried to create a formula which could basically give the probabilities of getting at least the specified cards combinations, and any other random cards (which can contain some more combinations). Here was my idea : $$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}13\\l\end{pmatrix}\cdot{\begin{pmatrix}4\\k\end{pmatrix}}^l\cdot\begin{pmatrix}52-kl\\n-kl\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}52\\n\end{pmatrix}}$$
While $\begin{pmatrix}52-kl\\n-kl\end{pmatrix}$ was intended to compute the number of different possible combinations for the remaining $n-kl$ specified cards, it appears that this formula leads to probabilities superior to one. I believe it counts two combinations of different orders as two different combinations, but I can't figure out where does it. So after so much text here's my real question : where is this wrong ?

Comment: Your formula for *exactly* three different two of a kind is correct.  Your extension to at least three different two of a kind overcounts.

Comment: As expected yes ... Should I try using a different structure instead of the single 52-kl C n-kl ?

Comment: I am not sure about what probability you are looking for. It it is three different two of a kind or $4$ different two of a kind, calculate the probability of each and add.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your first formula, what if $n = 52$?

Comment: Answer to André : I am trying to find the probability of the following event : we choose l and k to determine how many two, three, or four of a kind do we want **at least**, and n the number of cards we draw, which means out of the wanted two, three or four of a kind we can have anything (including some more two, three or four of kind since we want **at least** l k of a kind. Hopefully I explained it well.

Answer to Adam : according to all I've been calculating with the formula using www.desmos.com, it looks like have 13 four of a kind (basically the whole) deck is certain for $n=52$.

Comment: While all other possible values of k and l lead to a probability of 0 as it's impossible to have less than 13 four of a kind for $n=52$ as this involves taking the whole deck. I think the formula is correct for $n=52$ so.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand it now.

Comment: Allright, I'll be here for further information if you need.

Comment: You want to find the probability of at least $l$ sets of $k$ of a kind, which will be equal to $1$ minus the probability of getting less than $l$ sets. So if you have the probability of getting exactly $l$ sets as $P(k,l,n) $ you could use $$P(\text{at least } l \text{ sets}) = 1- \sum^{l-1}_{i=0} P(k,i,n)$$

Comment: Nice and easy way of doing it, I just didn't think to that ... That wouldn't exactlly work for all other possible cases but this is only due to my formula not allowing to compute the probability of multiple combinations using different values for $k$. However this is a great solution, thanks for your help !